# How to solve EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension issue while upgrade enterprise library version 5.0 to 6.0?

Tags: .net, vb.net, logging, unity-container, enterprise-library

I'm getting the EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension is not defined error while upgrade Enterprise library version 5.0 to 6.0.

Code:

```
container.AddNewExtension(Of EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension)
```

When I Googled, I got the below solution. Could anyone provide any example to implement the below solution?

> The Enterprise Library blocks no longer use the Unity container to
>   resolve instances. You should remove all calls to the AddNewExtension
>   method of the Unity container from your code. If your application
>   currently resolves Enterprise Library objects from the container, you
>   must either manually register the required types in the Unity
>   container, or modify your application to use the static facades in the
>   blocks to configure and retrieve the Enterprise Library objects your
>   application uses.